# Append .mov/.avi files with a mac

Tags: mac, video, editing

Simple question really... I have multiple movies that I have taken from my camera that I would just like to simply append to one another.  No processing or anything.

I usually use iMovie but for some reason this is taking forever and usually errors out right before the end.

Are there any other options out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really easy answer for you Mike - especially if you have a newer Mac that comes with the complete (Pro) version of QuickTime.

In QuickTime Pro, simply copying and pasting (yes- just like text) will do what you want.  Saving does still take some time once a movie is appended.  Just bring the movie you want to append to the foreground, hit command-c and then go back to the movie you want to append to, move the playhead indicator to the end and press command-v.

(I wonder though if you don't have other issues with your iMovie/QuickTime installation if iMovie is crapping out on you before the end?  Do you have Perian or any other 3rd party codec pack installed that could be causing problems?)

Josh

Comment: I bought Quicktime 7 Pro but I cant install Quicktime 7 because it says I have a newer version... That version being Quicktime X... Thoughts on that?

Comment: Mike - as I caveated in the first response - if you have a newer Mac, it will have these features built-in (no need to purchase anything).  Quicktime X will have the above mentioned features.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use mkvmerge. Just click the append button for however many files you have (must be same filetype, codec, dimensions,etc).

It of course makes a mkv (which needs perian to play), but you can remux to AVI with the AVI component or mov/mp4 by saving as QT mov or MP4 (passthrough options)